# How do I add an uncountable inflection for a non-word character in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pluralize

In a Rails app I have a number of measurements to display in a human readable form that include both a value and units.  Sometimes the units string needs to be pluralized like '1 minute, 2 minutes' but other times not like '1 kg, 2 kg'.  I was able to solve this by adding 'kg' do the list of `inflect.uncountable` in inflections.rb.  However, adding '%' to the list had no effect.  I confirmed in the console that '%' was added to @uncountables, but calling `pluralize(90, '%')` still returns `90 %s`.

I was able to get around this by doing `inflect.irregular '%', '%'` but that doesn't seem like the proper use of irregular.

Is there something I can add like an escape character to get rails to recognize '%' in the uncountables array?  Or alternatively, is there a better way to handle this outside of inflections?

For reference, inflections.rb right now looks like

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  # inflect.plural /^(ox)$/i, '\1en'
  # inflect.singular /^(ox)en/i, '\1'
  inflect.irregular '%', '%'
  inflect.uncountable %w( bpm kg mL )
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inflect.uncountable` works only with words, or better said, with whatever Regex deems as being a word. I'm not sure if this is a shortcoming of the implementation or the intended behavior.

`inflect.irregular '%', '%'` looks like a perfect workaround to me.